# Регулярные выражения в Java, проблема с Matcher.find()

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Имеется паттерн для поиска url в тексте.
Т.к. совпадений может быть несколько использую `Matcher.find()`. Однако после перехода в тело цикла при выходе любого метода Matcher'a получаю `exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found`. Хотя в проверочном тексте точно есть 2 совпадения. 
Если делать в теле `Matcher.reset()` то поведение ещё более странное: после каждой команды, даже если это создание строки как будто происходит вызов find(). 
В чём может быть проблема, или может я не так понимаю механику работы методов `Matcher` ?
Пример кода:

```
Pattern urlPattern = Pattern.compile("((https?|ftp|telnet)?://)?([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,128}\\.)+([a-zA-Z]{2,4})+(:[0-9]{0,5})?(/[a-zA-Z0-9.,_@%&?+=\\~/#-]*)?");  
Matcher urlMatcher = urlPattern.matcher(newText.toString());

while(urlMatcher.find()){
    //обработка
}
```

Comment: Вы проверяли, вот эти ваши 2 совпадения в тексте подходят под вашу маску?

Comment: Само собой проверял, да подходят, как я сказал в цикл я попадаю.

Comment: Регекс не совсем соответствует желаемому.  
Например  

    ://aaaa.aa
Будет найден как совпадение.  
Доменом будет `[a-z]` четное число раз или 3 раза, а не 2-4 раза.  
Ну и по мелочам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена. Каким то образом во время отладки некорректно отрабатывали методы Matcher.
После прогона без режима отладки всё отработало корректно.